# Log of page load times

Tags: optimization, performance

I am doing some page speed optimisation on a rather large website. I would like to be able to record the overall loading time for each page on my site. So, from request to completion of all elements loading.

Can anyone recommend software/tools/etc that will provide me with a log of pages along with their total loading time so I can target the pages that take the longest?

I should probably add that I am already aware of firebug, Yslow!, Page Speed plugin and 'Site Performance' in Google Webmaster Tools. Webmaster tools provides the closest answer to my problem, but only the top 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try log parser... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910447

Apart from that, not totally related to your query... this would be a good tool as well for analysis.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=60585590-57DF-4FC1-8F0C-05A286059406